# how to reduce multiple punctuation marks to just one from text file in java

Tags: java, regex, punctuation

I have some text files that contain multiple punctuation marks, so I need to reduce those to single punctuation marks.

Here is some sample text:

```
They are working in London..... he is a Java developer !!!!! they are playing------ She is working_______
```

This is the required output:

```
They are working in London.he is a Java developer !they are playing- She is working_
```

I need some help with the Java regex.

Thanks

Comment: Have you already tried anything that didn't work and that you could share with us?

Comment: Try playing around at http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backreference (`\1+`) to match repeated character.

Try following:

```
String text = "They are working in London..... he is a Java developer !!!!! they are playing------ ---- ---- She is working_______";
String replaced = text.replaceAll("(?:([-.!_])\\1+\\s*)+", "$1");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

prints

```
They are working in London.he is a Java developer !they are playing-She is working_
```

Comment: its working for continuous punctuation marks, if they are separated by white space like this ---- -------------------------------- --------- ---------------------please suggest me the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
   String str = "They are working in London..... he is a Java developer !!!!! they are playing-----She is working_______";
   String newStr = str.replaceAll("([|\\-|\\.|\\!|\\_])\\1+", "$1");
   System.out.println(newStr);
```

Live [Demo](http://ideone.com/1dy6A2)

Out put

```
They are working in London. he is a Java developer ! they are playing-She is working_
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

/([.;,?!-_]){2,}/$1/